# SELENIUM - Dropdowns in popupwindow

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My script goes like this - from main page click a button which opens a window with search criteria which contains drop down to select options, when I select values and search in popupwindow, nothing is happening.

it stalls in popupwindow with selected value in dropdown but the search click function doesn't execute.

Comment: Does the search button click event execute if you click on it manually?

Comment: yes if I click manually it gives results

Comment: Okay - so in the new pop-up window, the selection rvent if dropdoen takes place but the search button click event doesnt. Correct?

Comment: My question is two things -1) is the selection drop down in new form 2) does the selection event fire in script?

Comment: yes it is in new form and the selection event is in script by selectvisible command option

Comment: it is doing only one action in the pop up window , when I commented the dropdown code, search button followed by clear button, it is executing search button and stalls , clear action doesn't take place. My question is how perform actions in pop up window. I tried switch window but it seems like the window stays in the main page itself, control is not passed to pop window.I used windowhandles but no luck...

Comment: Can you please put the code?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("hButton")).click();
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchHistory"))).selectByValue("Name");
driver.findElement(By.id("searchHButton")).click();

Comment: do driver.findElement(By.id("searchHButton")).sendKeys("\n") instead of .Click()

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy it is working